# Installing Drupal 7 - "Already installed" error?

Tags: installation, drupal-7

I keep hitting this "Already Installed" error (it seems to be pretty common - http://drupal.org/node/127843) but I couldn't find the solution to it.

I uploaded settings.php with all the correct info, but it would say "Already Installed."

So I tried deleting settings.php, leaving default.settings.php intact.  It would take me through the normal installation process until "Set up database".  After entering the correct info (same info as in settings.php), I click on "Save and continue" and it takes be right back to the "Already Installed" error.

No matter what I do, it just doesn't seem to want to let me get to the next step (Install profile).

I've been doing this loop for the past hour.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is Drupal 7.9.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the tables from the MySQL database...if they exist then the Drupal install will (rightly) abort so as not to overwrite a potentially existing website.

Comment: There are no tables in the database - it's completely empty.

Comment: I think your mysql user ur providing to drupal does not have priviliges to create table

Answer (score 0):

I tried finding a solution in the [Drupal community](http://drupal.org/node/127843), but failed. Then I tried restarting my MySQL server, which oddly resolved the issue.

Hope that helps someone out there.